# Adding a map to contact form

Tags: magento2, google-map

How can I add a custom google maps on the custom contact page? I'm using Magento 2.1.9 and I can't find where to do this on the admin panel so I don't know which code should I edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add this code snippet to where you want the Map to be displayed.

`<iframe style="border: 0;" src="Link"  width="" height=""></iframe>`

Specify the width and height to what your website needs, add the link to your google maps and you should be good to go!